# "Misuse" vs. "Abuse"

Tags: meaning, difference, legalese

What are the differences between ***misuse*** and ***abuse***?

This is what is listed for **misuse** in the dictionary:

> **Verb**: Use (something) in the wrong way or for the wrong purpose.
>
> **Noun**: The wrong or improper use of something: "their misuse can have dire consequences".

And **abuse**:

> **Verb**: Use (something) to bad effect or for a bad purpose; misuse.
>
> **Noun**: The improper use of something.

Is there any general difference or does it depend on the context?

I always have trouble to recognize which one to use.

I am also interested in how the word is used in the other context like law and crime.

Comment: What do you mean by your recent edit? I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: What matters? I don't understand what you mean by "grounds of humanity, legal, and sociological subjects." Can you give an example of a situation where you are wondering about their use?

Comment: I am a native speaker, but I still cannot understand what you are asking for. Those are extremely broad topics. Why do you think that the usage would be different in those topics?

Comment: Sorry I can't help more. I have read that sentence a lot in academic legal articles of native speakers. I mean "on grounds of". Because it will provide serious consequences if you do not choose an appropriate word when you are talking about your legal rights or are defending of yourself or are writing for an authority.

Comment: First of all, I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of the phrase "on grounds of..." in a way that makes what you are asking hard to understand. Second of all, you are right that in those situations, word choice is important, but why do you think that the answers below are insufficient for those situations?

Comment: Perhaps we can discuss this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/english-language-learners)

Comment: I think the question is correct and enough for answering.I am not interested in chat and will leave it here. thanks for answering. Take a look at this: http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+grounds

Comment: I know what that phrase means, and you are not using it correctly. I think the phrase that you are looking for is "With respect to...", but either way, it is unclear what you are asking for. "Humanity, legal, and sociological subjects" is extraordinarily broad. Do you have a particular example where you are confused about the usage of those words?

Comment: I have added to my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Could you please join us in chat, then? I'm discussing this with someone else there, and neither of us are able to figure out what you are asking.

Comment: When asking a question like this, we hope and assume you've looked the words up in a dictionary beforehand. In future, please include these dictionary definitions in your question, and then try to use them to explain what you still don't understand. The underlying premise of the question is perfectly fine, but if you had shown more research that would be helpful. I'm not sure why you think the words would have a different meaning in legal/sociological/etc. contexts. Can you explain that further please, so we can help you?

Comment: I have done it and if the dictionaries had my answer I have never asked it here. I think I have explained it above. Nothing have to add.

Comment: @PersianCat I didn't say the dictionary should have your answer. I said that if you used a dictionary and *didn't* find an answer, posting the research you found in the dictionary in your question would improve the question. Then you could say "I've looked them both up but I still don't understand." But that's all right; just keep this in mind for the future please :)

Comment: I though it is clear when you are asking a question here you have done a research in the dictionaries before it. I do not think it is necessary. It is obvious.

Comment: We'd all love it if it were obvious that people had done some research in the dictionaries before coming here and posting to ask for clarification, but in many cases it's not obvious at all (or worse, it's obvious that they didn't do any research; that's why questions get closed as "general reference").  Including some detail about "here's what the dictionary said, here's what it doesn't address, and that's why I'm still confused" helps tremendously in focusing the answer on your real issue.

Comment: (In this case, since the second definition of *abuse* (at http://www.m-w.com ) says "misuse" and the second definition of *misuse* says "abuse", it's clear that there's plenty of potential overlap.  :-) )

Comment: @WendiKidd, Hellion, Persian Cat: I've added the definitions of misuse and abuse to the question.

Comment: @PersianCat: Your caveat "on the grounds of humanity,legal and sociological subjects too" is excessively broad (remember: questions on ELL must be *reasonably scoped* as per our FAQ). You might want to narrow it down to something like "*I am also interested in how the word is used in the context of narcotics (drugs) and relationships*", which would match your answer.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

People above sent good answers however It was not enough and complete. I searched more and could find that these two words are [synonyms](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abuse) of each other in general conversations but should not to use them in the matters on the grounds of law,crime and sociology because they imply different meanings which may have serious consequences if you apply them incorrectly. For example:

1) [Drugs](http://www.ehow.com/about_5474373_drug-misuse-vs-drug-abuse.html):

> ***Misuse***
>
> Drug misuse is when you use a prescription drug for a purpose other than the one for which it was prescribed. A great example of this is using psychostimulants prescribed for attention deficit hyperactivity disorder for weight loss. Psychostimulants help individuals who have attention deficits focus more easily by stimulating certain chemicals in the brain responsible for concentration. Because of the intense focusing on tasks at hand, this drug is prone to misuse because individuals find that the stimulant keeps them focused on tasks they are doing while keeping hunger signals at bay.
>
> ***Abuse***
>
> Drug abuse is when you become addicted to the effects of a prescription that has been misused. For example, psychostimulant misusers are prone to become abusers when they get addicted to the stimulant's effects and therefore need to take higher doses more often to achieve the same effects. Drug abuse happens when an addiction to the misused drug is formed. Drug abuse carries a much bigger chance of endangering the health of the abuser

Or [here](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-abuse-and-misuse/):

> 1. **Drug misuse** is the improper use of medications for purely therapeutic gains but does not include the improper use of drugs taken for pleasure and the like.
> 2. **Drug abuse** is a more repetitive and willful habit of taking drugs for the purpose of pleasure, ecstasy and euphoria but does not include the repeated use of drugs for therapeutic purposes

2) Crimes related to the [Relationships](http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oG7mRgb41RSl0AWmlXNyoA?p=abuse%20women%20men&fr2=sb-top&fr=yfp-t-900)

I found that ***abuse*** in relationships means rape,beating,psychological violence,financial and emotional charging but ***misuse*** is meaningless.

Comment: If your question had specifically mentioned drugs or relationships instead of "humanity,legal and sociological subjects," we could have commented on those particular areas instead of trying to guess what you were asking about. In either case, the distinctions you have drawn when talking about drugs and relationships are no different than the distinctions between the two words in any other context.

Comment: I think the reason for the downvotes is because 1. The claim that "misuse" and "abuse" are synonyms in regular usage is incorrect and 2. The distinction that you draw for the cases of drugs and relationships is exactly the same as the distinction between the words in regular conversation as given in the two most upvoted answers above, so actually it's this answer which does not add anything to the others.

Answer (score 12):

"Misuse" has a generally less severe connotation than "abuse."  Abuse would usually be something that someone does intentionally or without regard for consequences, while misuse is more likely to be unintentional.

The meaning is the same in the humanities, sociology, legal studies, and all other fields.

Answer (score 9):

The two *can* be used synonymously, but there is generally a difference at least of degree between them, and often of intended meaning.

To "misuse" is "to use incorrectly". For example, if you take a screwdriver and try to use it to paint a picture, you are misusing it; the screwdriver is not designed for painting, and will not do a good job when pressed into that service, but neither the paint, the picture, nor the screwdriver will be damaged as a result of your action.

To "abuse" is "to use excessively or damagingly".  For example, if you take a screwdriver and try to use it to pry up a manhole cover, you are abusing it; although a screwdriver can often be used to pry up small objects, a manhole cover is much too large for an average screwdriver and you are likely to end up with a bent, damaged screwdriver and an unmoved manhole by the time you give up.

In terms of sociology, as @Daniel has also said, the usage is essentially the same, although I'd say you are much less likely to encounter the word "misuse" in this context (or if you do, it is entirely synonymous with "abuse").  If an employer makes his workers engage in a dangerous action without taking appropriate safety precautions, he is abusing the workers ("using them in a way likely to cause damage"), even if they don't actually get injured.

Comment: The damage may not be to the item being used, as well.  For example, using a screwdriver to open a car door - it might work, but will destroy the lock.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy, that is very true.  In that case I might be inclined to say that you have misused the screwdriver and abused the lock.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

The two words are **NOT** synonyms of each other in general conversations, as you have suggested. The examples you give actually illustrate the differences mentioned by the others who have replied.

**Misuse** is far less serious than ***abuse***. ***Misuse*** may be a mistake, but could be intentional. ***Abuse*** is almost certainly intentional and may have serious consequences.

In your examples:

- Drug ***misuse*** is when you use a drug for the wrong purpose, either by mistake or intentionally.
- Drug ***abuse*** involves ***misusing*** a drug to such an extent that it becomes addiction and "willful habit". Then it is ***abuse***.

Hence, as in other general usage, ***abuse*** is more serious than ***misuse***.

You're correct that ***misuse*** is not generally used in talking about relationships, because you don't usually talk about ***misusing*** a person. But ***abusing*** a person is serious.

I repeat, your examples of usage of the words in connection with drugs and relationships are merely illustrating - or extensions of - the more general differences, albeit that they have generally accepted fairly specific meanings in those fields.

Comment: Your answer doesn't add a new thing to above answers. You are judging my answer in your answer so your answer is not a real answer. Furthermore, misuse and abuse are synonyms generally but not in the specific matters as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try a word, "deliberately.". I was ended up on your posts because I was trying to answer the same question.  As you said, according to dictionaries, they are synonymous.  But practically, we weigh much more severalty on the word, abuse, than misuse.

This is not linguistic definition but, for example, in the field of Justice against domestic violence or intimate partner violence, we use the word, "deliberately," when we define abuse.

As some of other sources saying, abuse is an use of something with the deliberate intention for improper purpose.  So often misuse can happen without the caution of consequence while abuse often happens with a clear acknowledgement of consequence.  It's easy to understand why many abuse-rs can get away with consequence.

You can also say abuse means to use something by manipulating it's function for improper reason.

Answer (score -1):

In short, misuse is when someone is doing something wrong but he actually don't know that i am using it or doing it in wrong way that means misuse is unintentional while abusing is wrong use (misuse of something) intentionally.